# button change color after click - focus not working good

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular5

I want to make buttons in the navigation panel which, after selecting the page, will take on a different color and If i click next page return to old color. I use material designs from angulara. I am trying to make color changes in css in the way below. The color after clicking changes but when you click on the context on the page returns back to the old color.

```css
.btn {
  padding: 5px 20px  0px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.btn:hover {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   color: rgb(255,100,100);
 }
.btn:focus{
      color: rgb(255,102,100);
    }
.btn:active {
  color: rgb(255,102,100);
}
```

```html
<button mat-button class="mainPageButton btn" id="btnHousing" routerLink="/home">Strona Główna</button>
```

Comment: I think you should use JavaScript for this.
When the button is clicked or focused on, append the `active` class to it, upon losing focus, remove the `active` class.

Comment: You should try to use a routerLinkActive="active" attribute which adds a class active on your element

Answer (score 1):

**Try to use this code in angular 5**

And here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gy2an/8/

```js
//this app:
angular.module('myApp', ['autoActive']);

window.location.hash = '#/'; //All hash paths need to start with a /, it happens automaticaly with ngResource and the like...

//the module we are demonstrating:
(function () {
    angular.module('autoActive', [])
        .directive('autoActive', ['$location', function ($location) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: false,
            link: function (scope, element) {
                function setActive() {
                    var path = $location.path();
                    if (path) {
                        angular.forEach(element.find('li'), function (li) {
                            var anchor = li.querySelector('a');
                            if (anchor.href.match('#' + path + '(?=\\?|$)')) {
                                angular.element(li).addClass('active');
                            } else {
                                angular.element(li).removeClass('active');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                setActive();

                scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', setActive);
            }
        }
    }]);
}());
```

```css
li.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div auto-active>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/?some=data">This link points to #/fun1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/fun2?some=data">This link points to #/fun2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/fun3">This link points to #/fun3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/fun4">This link points to #/fun4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/fun5?some=data">This link points to #/fun5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When i put function in my typescript it is still not working

Comment: Dude that's angularjs you're like so far off